# Scope in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

You can see the last lines of these two models use the same code:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :last_day, 
  where('positions.created_at > ? AND positions.hidden = ?',
  DateTime.now.in_time_zone("Sofia").yesterday.beginning_of_day + 10.hours, false)
end

class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :notify_today,
  joins(:tags => :positions).
  where('positions.created_at > subscribers.created_at 
  AND positions.created_at > ? AND positions.hidden = ?', 
  DateTime.now.in_time_zone("Sofia").yesterday.beginning_of_day + 10.hours, false)
end
```

Is it possible to reuse the 'last_day' scope somehow in the second model?

Comment: If you removed Subscriber's join relationship to exclusively its join to `position`, -- because Position already has those parameters set, wouldn't that be all you need? Sorry if you already tried this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where()` and `joins()` both return `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects, and they have a method called `merge()` which can merge other `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects. Therefore, you can simply do this

```
scope :notify_today, joins(:tags => :positions).merge(Position.last_day)
```

Also, `&` is an alias to `merge()`, so you should also be able to do this

```
scope :notify_today, joins(:tags => :positions) & Position.last_day
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I also find info about 'merge' here: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3